# How to validate optional field in angular 2?

Tags: angular, validation

i have an email field which is optional but if has value should match the 
email pattern ?

what about if the form has many optional fields ,like website ,phone ,etc ?

by the way am using FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators form @angular/forms

Comment: empty value is not email :)  what about the website validation do you have html5 type also   :)

Comment: You are using Reactive Forms, so you can add and remove Validators as needed to a Form Control using `setValidators/clearValidators/updateValueandValidity`

Comment: will try these options thank you

Comment: Some information on those: https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl

Answer (score 11):

Solved this by creating an optionalValidator:

```
import { ValidatorFn, AbstractControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

export function optionalValidator(validators?: (ValidatorFn | null | undefined)[]): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {

        return control.value ? Validators.compose(validators)(control) : null;
    };
}
```

In my reactive form:

```
this.form = this._fb.group({
      email: [this.contact.email, [optionalValidator([Validators.maxLength(255), Validators.email])]]
    });
```

Comment: at `Validators.compose(validators)(control) : null` for validators showing error type `undefined` is not assignable to type `ValidatorFn | null | undefined`

Answer (score 2):

ex:

```
contactForm:FormGroup = new FormGroup({});

ngOnInit() {
const validateEmail = "[a-zA-Z0-9._\-]+[@]+[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+[.]+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}";
this.contactForm.addControl("email", new FormControl('', Validators.pattern(validateEmail));
}
```

this way you can create optional fields but when you have data that need to be validated

Edit: Added *-* to allowed characters

Comment: This regex is far from complete for a good validation. The email: " "_@local is a valid email address but does not pass this test.